# Variable from expression in SSIS SQL statement

Tags: ssis

I wish to use a single Execute SQL Task component in SSIS to gather two values as variables from expressions and used as parameters in the SQL statement.  I can create the expressions to gather the values put putting it all together is not working so far

I have a variable called GetCurrentDT (get current date time) as a DateTime type and using the GetDate() in the expression

I have a variable called CountCurrent_SQL as a String type and in the expression - "Select Count(*) from dbo.myChecktable" and this expression evaluates okay

I have a variable called CountCurrent as a Integer type and in the expression I was trying to CAST this as an Integer from @User::CountCurrent_SQL but this fails

My intention is to use GetCurrentDT and CountCurrent values as Mapped Paraneters in the Executes SQL Tasks actual SQLStatement property as follows,

INSERT INTO dbo.Transact_Tracking(TransactCommence, TransactCurrentCount)
VALUES (?,?);

How do I resolve the issues so far and complete this?

Followed several YouTube and Web page guides but so far nothing I found does exactly what I wish to process

I expect the Execute SQL Task to gather the two SQL parameter values through expressions into variables and use them as parameters in the SQLstatement property in the Execute SQL Task

Can this be done?

EDIT - I have managed to get this done with one variable, the GETDATE() one but still having issues with two

Comment: Do you have a typo in your question `INSERT INTO dbo.Transact_Tracking(TransactCommence, TransactCurrentCount) VALUES (??);` or the actual code? You should have `VALUES(?,?);`

Comment: And as I come more awake... `CountCurrent_SQL` is a query. and `CountCurrent` you expect to be the results of invoking CountCurrent_SQL? If so, what server/database is dbo.Transact_Tracking on as well as dbo.myChecktable?

Comment: @billinkc Thanks for response.  I have edited question to resolve the typo you highlighted, also I have the first variable working and inserting.  The database is a SQL Server database on a remote server from local development machine.  It will be deployed on server hosting the SQL server.  Yes, CountCurrent I want as the result of CountCurrent_SQL

Comment: Are the two tables in the same server and database?

Comment: @billinkc for this Execute SQL Task - yes, the tables are in the same database and server

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use only a single Execute SQL Task? Is there a particular reason you need CountCurrent_SQL to be a string variable? You can probably use multiple Execute SQL statements to set your variables to the correct value and datatypes, with a third Execute SQL task to do the insert using the two variables. Once you confirm the answers to my questions, I can write up a full answer.

Comment: @digital.aaron Thanks for response.  I have used the method you are suggesting before and it works yes, but i would like to reduce the amount of Execute SQL Tasks.  Basically what i want to know is how to create a variable that will set to a value of a SQL select in the expression!!???

Comment: Why do you want to reduce the number of Execute SQL Tasks?